# Creating dialog from function, can't send message - MS Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

Building a bot using NodeJS and the Microsoft Bot framework - inside my dialog I have a function, I'm unable to send a session.send("") from getDetails function, but I am able to start a new dialog. When I start this new dialog I'm not able to send any messages either. I've tried passing session to the function and this didn't work either: Code (this is inside a dialog and runs etc)

```
    function (session, results, next) {


        if (results.response) {

                    var place = results.response; 

                    getDetails(session, place, function (err, geoData) {

                        if (err) {
                        console.log(err); 

                        } else {

                              var formattedString = place.streetAddress + " " + geoData[0].extra.neighborhood + " " + place.postalCode;
                              console.log(formattedString);
                              connectSQL(formattedString, function(returnValue) {


                                session.send("hello-connectSQL");
                                session.beginDialog("sendLocation");

                           });                    

                        }

                    })

                }

    }
]);

bot.dialog("sendLocation", [
    function(session, args){

        console.log("hello"); //This successfully outputs to console. 
        session.send("message"); //Doesn't send. 
            }

])
```

edit: getDetails code:

```
async function getDetails(session, place, callback) {
    await geocoder.reverse( {
        lat:place.geo.latitude, 
        lon:place.geo.longitude
    })
    .then(res =>  {
        geoData = res; 

        callback(null, geoData); 
    })
    .catch(err =>  {
        console.log(err); 
        callback(err); 
    })
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide code of `getDetails` function?

Comment: Updated with code. thanks

Comment: The function 'connectSQL' might also help here, as the console.log() working but the session.send() not working indicates it's maybe a callback issue.